# WAMP not displaying embedded .swf file

Tags: php, flash, wamp

Good Afternoon,

When I publish a .swf move to a specific folder, lets say "c:/wamp/www/test/index.html". I can test it by opening the .html file that comes with it. It plays the movie perfectly.

This also happens to be in my wamp folder. I start wamp and I try and load up the file using wamp:

"http://127.0.0.1/test/index.html

The webpage loads up but my movie does not start. I can see the control bar at the bottom of the flash object but it looks like it's stuck loading the file or something. Something is wrong.

I go ahead and check my apache error log file:

```
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 24 2011 19:57:51
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5000
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Child 5000: Child process is running
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Child 5000: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Child 5000: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Child 5000: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Apr 12 00:17:42 2012] [notice] Child 5000: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I also checked my apace access log file:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2012:00:17:49 +0400] "GET /OktomberiSchool/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10878
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2012:00:17:49 +0400] "GET /OktomberiSchool/images/master_images/table_1_top_left_home.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2012:00:17:51 +0400] "GET /OktomberiSchool/webpages/vidoes/vidoes.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10062
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Apr/2012:00:17:51 +0400] "GET /OktomberiSchool/webpages/vidoes/video_01.swf HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

I can't spot the errors.

Anybody have any ideas what's going on?

Comment: if you right-click the movie does it show "... not loaded"?

Comment: Hey Michael, nope, just tried that. I forgot to add that when I create something like a slide show using flash, that plays no problem. I'm just having a problem playing a flash video.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the .fla using adobe Flash and seen this error:

"The video player is in the connection error state. It enters this state when a video stream attempted to load but was unsuccessful. There are two possible reasons for the error: no connection to the server or the stream was not found."

It then struck me that it was not finding the video. So I moved the video into the same folder, produced the .swf file again and Bob is your uncle. (It worked.)

Once again, I hope this solution helps somebody.